# Effects of dropping in and out of zero G on a space station

Tags: biology, gravity, space-constructs

I'm writing a book that involves having a space station that acts as a way point between Earth and a new planet. (Hard"ish" SF, or as "Hard" as I can make it...)

The Station sits at the mouth of a wormhole and because the aperture is geostationary to the sun, the new Earth-like planet passes by on a yearly basis.
As a result, the space station acts as a large depot. Cargo from Earth comes through the wormhole daily, but can only be transported to the new world during a narrow "season".

The station has to accommodate lots of workers, and most of the work is done in zero G. But the station also acts as "Hotel" for space tourists, and has rotating habitat ring.

Depending on the answer to this question I need to decide whether the workers would also accommodate the ring, or be better off in their own continuous zero G area.

To the point...
My question is this.
Would the workforce suffer from dropping into 8 hour zero G shifts then spending the next 16 hours in 1G, over a week. Or would they be better off spending a week solely in zero G, and then a week in 1G?

Essentially:
**What would be the safest 1G/0G rotation for such a workforce?**

I've read various notes on the long term effects of zero G in relation to Mars missions etc, but found nothing about what, (if any) effects dropping in and out of 0G on a daily basis would incur.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for worldbuilding SE. You'll need a ton of handwavium to have a static object near earth's orbit, though, and even if you manage that, earth will zip by at more than 100000Km/h

Comment: Far Space Station sitting at the mouth of a wormhole... did you google for star trek deep space nine?

Comment: Sorry, from the point of view of the fiction, the apertures anchor to the strongest gravitational object at the point they occur, so the Earth end is fixed to earth's gravity, and the "other end" is fixed to the sun. Would it help if I disregard the fiction part, and just ask about the effects of dropping in and out of Zero G on a work shift basis, and leave the other stuff for the Worldbuilding lot?

Comment: @Tommy without wishing to bounce your question back and forth, if you'd just asked about 1g/0g cycles you'd have had a better chance of getting a good answer out of the space exploration peeps, but never mind. FYI: "geostationary" is only a word that makes sense when talking about orbits (and specifically "geo" means "earth" here) and your object clearly isn't orbiting but suspended by magic and that may have issues in a hard scifi setting.

Comment: I'll try and explain... The aperture at "our" end sits next to the Earth station where it was opened which is geostationary, above the UK. The wormhole fixes to that specific gravitational point.  So it moves around the sun as the Earth does without causing a tear. At the other end the aperture is in space and nowhere near a planet at the point it opens. It "locks" to the nearest gravity source, in this case the "other end's" sun/star. so it effectively stays in place while other celestial bodies move in their own orbits.

Comment: @Tommy if it orbits the sun at earth's orbital radius, the distance between the earth and the wormhole will remain constant. If it maintains the same distance from the sun as the earth but does _not_ circle the sun at the same rate as the earth, it does not orbit. There is no plausible way I can think of for an object to "stick" in space like this without active support (eg, as a statite or with some hidden reactionless drive system) and as such it must be held in place with magic.

Comment: I'm just going to stop metioning the bloody wormhole... :)

Comment: I need it to be stuck in one place in the system for the plot to work.

Comment: @Tommy its a reasonable plan ;-) but as I've pointed out before, there's no need for your weird magical wormhole positioning idea to get the environment you wanted. Orbital phasing is a thing, after all.

Comment: What I need is for the wormhole station to be (effectively) stationary while the nearest world orbits the sun, so that there are distinct "seasons". One where travel is cheaper and easier, and the other where it's dangerous and expensive to try. (I'm already basically cheating by the wormhole opening on the same "level" as the planet's orbit, making any travel between the two exist on the same flat plane... about a 1 in 180 chance I reckon...)

Comment: @Tommy orbital phasing _already does that_. We already have departure windows to other bodies in the solar system, outside of which delta-V budgets and/or travel times go way up, both of which can involve considerable increases in risk and cost . This also avoids the massive 30km/s delta-V required to enter/exit orbit at the far end of the wormhole, FWIW.

Comment: @Starfish Prime I kind of get it... I'm a writer, not much of a scientist and it narks me when I don't understand something first time. I now need to work out how to ask the question of exactly how to figure out "Where" in the new solar system the wormhole needs to be in order to for the narrative to have the regular "seasons" from the POV of Earth travellers that my story needs. Thanks for putting up with me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98163/discussion-between-starfish-prime-and-tommy).

Comment: @Tommy says '_It "locks" to the nearest gravity source, in this case the "other end's" sun/star. so it effectively stays in place while other celestial bodies move in their own orbits_'.  This seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of gravity.  Objects in freefall can't "stay in place".  An object can be "locked" to the sun's gravity in one of two ways:  it falls into the sun, or it orbits the sun.  Standing still is never an option.

Comment: Thanks Ray. But I've had that conversation with Starfish, above. He's very kindly helped me with some ideas on how to overcome this in a more "Real" scientific sense. I wish I'd never mentioned the plot device that this question anchors to. I'm going to stop giving the fictional background set ups to my questions... I just want to know about upset tummy's on space workers... ;)

Comment: I think the issue here is that the answer to your question isn't actually known yet.  I'm sure NASA would *like* to run tests to learn the answer to your question, and probably will at the first opportunity; but the fact is that we don't have a space station with a centrifuge habitat with which to test the question

Comment: @Tommy Have you considered having the wormhole in a halo orbit about a lagrangian point? Additionally, you cannot have a geostationary orbit above the UK, all geostationary orbits are equatorial.

Answer (score 4):

[Space sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_adaptation_syndrome) is a syndrome that hits many astronauts.

> space sickness is a condition experienced by as many as half of all space travelers during their adaptation to weightlessness once in orbit.

By shifting on a regular base from microgravity to normal gravity doesn't sound like a smart idea, since it will increase the likelihood of getting sick. It is way better to have longer periods of permanence in microgravity, to spread the impact of sickness on the stay: if one gets space sick on a 8 hours shift, the whole shift is good as gone, while if one gets space sick on a 4 weeks shift (just to throw in a long shift), the few lost hours will have a lower impact on the effectiveness of the worker.

Comment: Eh, you could just employ only people who don't get spacesick.

Comment: Thanks Dutch, any idea where I should go to ask about specifics of space sickness, such as  whether the "in and out" shift pattern I describe would be something that could be countered by something like Dramimine, or something that one would overcome after a while? (I seem to have a bad habit of posting these questions in the wrong place...)  Ideally I'd "like" to have the workers in the ring with the passengers,  but if common sense would dictate they would be throwing up all over, I'd have to rethink.

Comment: space sickness is on topic on Space.SE.

Comment: Thanks @Hobbes, I asked there first, unless there's a Space Stack other than the Space Exploration one I visited. I got migrated to here. (Which is where I was going to ask in the first place but feared getting migrated to a specific science based Stack). I don't want to waste time asking there again only to be told it's a duplicate of this question and sent back here.